# using multiple-dispatch for functions when they are defined in different modules (Julia)

Tags: module, julia, multiple-dispatch

I tried to use multiple-dispatch for functions that are defined in different modules in Julia, e.g.:

```
module A

export f
f(i::Integer) = println(i)

end

module B

export f
f(i::AbstractFloat) = println(i)

end

using .A, .B

f(.1)
```

But it returns an error

```
WARNING: both B and A export "f"; uses of it in module Main must be qualified
ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: f not defined
```

I understand that julia tries to avoid name conflicts in different modules. But in my case these `f` functions can be distinguished by their arguments but it still returns an error. In the docs, Julia offers three ways to solve the problem:

> 1. Simply proceed with qualified names like A.f and B.f. This makes the
>    context clear to the reader of your code, especially if f just happens
>    to coincide but has different meaning in various packages. For
>    example, degree has various uses in mathematics, the natural sciences,
>    and in everyday life, and these meanings should be kept separate.
> 2. Use the as keyword above to rename one or both identifiers, eg

```
julia> using .A: f as f

julia> using .B: f as g
```

> would make B.f available as g. Here, we are assuming that you did not
> use using A before, which would have brought f into the namespace.
>
> 3. When the names in question do share a meaning, it is common for one
>    module to import it from another, or have a lightweight “base” package
>    with the sole function of defining an interface like this, which can
>    be used by other packages. It is conventional to have such package
>    names end in ...Base (which has nothing to do with Julia's Base
>    module).

For the first two solutions, they can't solve my problem since I really need to display multiple-dispatch and they have to be defined in different modules, and I don't understand the 3rd solution. Could someone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function f() end

module A

export f
Main.f(i::Integer) = println(i)

end

module B

export f
Main.f(i::AbstractFloat) = println(i)

end

using .A, .B

f(.1)
```

Basically, make them the same function by defining a "prototype" function outside both of them and specialize that function twice in each submodule. Here because `module A` and B lives in global scope so I used `Main.`, you should use whatever is housing your sub modules

Comment: Thanks that helps a lot. The redefinition in front is inevitable, isn't it?

Comment: You can let one sub module use the function from the other sub module but then you have to make sure the order is correct

Comment: Technically, your first attempt defines two separate functions `f`, one in each module. Multiple dispatch only works on methods of the same function. This is what jling does, defines a single function `f` in `Main`, and then adds methods to it in the modules.

Comment: How should I implement this solution when I have modules defined in different files? E.g., module A in a.jl, module B in b.jl, the function `g` that uses `f` in c.jl, and the main module in the file d.jl?

Comment: pay attention to `include()` order I guess